# How do I solve "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Int'" error in guard?

Tags: swift, syntax-error, guard

I'm trying to initialize a variable using guard, but get the following error:

> Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Int'

This is my code:

```
guard let checkMarkPosition = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "showOnCustomButton") else {return}
```

I have read about similar errors on guard: [guard let error: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type not 'String'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37858071/guard-let-error-initializer-for-conditional-binding-must-have-optional-type-not)

but in that case it was that the code was force-unwrapped. In my case I don't use any `!`. I have tried adding `?` here and there to see what happens, but I still get the same error.

Comment: if you intent is to check if there is a value and if not return `nil` instead of `0`, you can use `object(forKey:) as? Int`.

Answer (score 4):

[Apple documentation says](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1407405-integer):

> The integer value associated with the specified key. If the specified key doesn‘t exist, this method returns 0.

Method `integer(forKey:)` returns `Int`, not `Int?` so this is not optional and you can't use guard here.

Comment: Ah, ok, so if there isn't a value saved at userDefault, it returns 0 not nil?

Comment: Yes, exactly :)

Comment: **"and you can't use guard here"** This is not true OP can use  `guard case let`

Answer (score 1):

`integer(forKey`return no optional ,  default is 0

```
let checkMarkPosition = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "showOnCustomButton")
```